# Can inactive users be set as inactive via apex, and automated for deletion?

Tags: apex

There is a builder for setting up accounts with their contacts, contracts, orders etc. and there is also an option to go into a similar builder to edit an already existing account/contract/contacts etc.

One option (this was started by someone else and then passed onto me...) is to edit or remove an existing contact from the account. However, the remove really doesn't do anything, because you can't delete users this way.

What my client has been doing in the meantime (she doesn't have admin access) is just making users inactive one-by-one as needed. Even then, she'd have to ask me to then delete whichever users.

```
Can this inactivation be done in apex within the builder as a function of
the (currently pointless) remove button?
```

...

```
Can inactive users be automatically deleted after some amount of time?
```

If the answer is no to either of these things, how might I go about using the remove button to remove the contacts from the related list even if they are still technically active?

Comment: a point of clarification? Are you talking about Contacts or Users? These are different objects

Comment: contacts, sorry about that!

Comment: also -- what do you mean by 'builder'?  'Process Builder' ?